# What is the quickest way to toggle hide/show hidden files on a Mac OS X Yosemite?

Tags: terminal, applescript, osx-yosemite, finder

I'm on Yosemite, and I want to toggle hide/show all the hidden files on a Mac.

Every-time, I want to do that I have to go to **Terminal.app** and run these command :

To show

`defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE`

To hide

`defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE`

I'm wondering if there is a better tweak out there that accomplish this in just a click of a button.

Comment: The answer from @user309603 worked perfectly for me in Yosemite.

Comment: You can also browse hidden files/folders on local storage in OS X using the FTP app Transmit. (On the View-menu in Transmit you can choose to show hidden files.) A quick solution for those who don't like using the Terminal.app

Answer (score 67):

I prefer using this shortcut:

<kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>

Comment: This is great. I was always using custom function in shell to control show/hide. Now I could ditch those functions and use this shortcut!

Comment: Does not seem to work on osx 10.8, is there another command to replace it?

Comment: Nice!! Worked here on macOS Mojave v10.14!!

Comment: Ahhh.. this is what I was missing last 5 years  thanks 

Answer (score 4):

Update, considering all comments:

```
try
    set state to (do shell script "defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles") as boolean
on error
    set state to false
end try

do shell script "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles " & (not state)

try
    tell application "Finder"
        set w to front window
        set t to (get target of w)
        if t is not startup disk then
            set the target of w to startup disk
        else
            set the target of w to home
        end if
        set the target of w to t
    end tell
end try

tell application (path to frontmost application as text)
    display notification "ShowAllFiles is now " & (not state)
end tell
```

Export the script as app and cmd-drag the app to the Finder window toolbar.

Comment: These are really good news. I've been using this script for years and didn't noticed the change. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: If you want to use this script with just one click, save it as an app and cmd-drag it to the toolbar of a Finder window. It's fast accessible in every window then!

Comment: How to "save it as an app": 1. Open ScriptEditor application. 2. Paste in the above script. 3. Select File :: Export (enter filename, select File Format = "application" and making it "Run Only")

Answer (score 4):

- Open finder.
- Hold down Cmd + Shift + . (dot)

And all your hidden files are visible.

Hold down Cmd + Shift + . (dot) to revert to original.

Answer (score 2):

I came across another solution by using Automator.

**Open Automator**
Select Services
Select Utilities -> Run Shell Script (drag it into the window on the right)

Top bar above code window.
Service receives: **no input** in **Finder**

Add the following code to show hidden files

```
status=`defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles`
if [ $status == true ];
then
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles false
else 
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles true
fi
killall Finder
```

Save the script.

**Make a shortcut**
Go to System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Services and find the Services you made showing hidden files. There might be a shortcut there if so test it out. If there is not shortcut there then add shift+cmd+. (period) as the shortcut.

To show hidden files use the shortcut: shift+cmd+. (period).
To hide the files use the same shortcut again.

OR click the desktop and go to in the top menu: Finder -> Services -> name of file to show hidden files. First time to show the files and second time to hide them.

**To delete Services scripts.**
Go to your hard drive -> user name -> Library -> Services -> and there you will see the Services Automator scripts.

Resources used:
https://discussions.apple.com/message/29357134#29357134

How to delete Automator services.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kaVHwhau1M4

Here is a tutorial that I made: https://www.easywebdesigntutorials.com/easily-show-hide-hidden-files-on-the-mac/

Answer (score 1):

Change "killall Finder" to "KillAll Finder" in user309603's script, save it as an applet somewhere, and it should work. That means that you can just write "ToggleVisible" or something in Spotlight, and it will do the changes.

I'd also wrap the alert box into a `tell application (path to frontmost application as text)` block, to ensure that it won't get lost.

Answer (score 1):

If you are french and got an azerty keyboard you have to add the fn key presse cmd + fn + maj + ; and you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

You can even download 'Secrets' preference pane, which gets installed in System Preferences. Hidden settings can be enabled/disabled.
https://code.google.com/p/blacktree-secrets/downloads/list